# Sitecore editing an item or using experience editor returns a 403 "Access Denied"

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor

We are currently `upgrading` from `Sitecore 10.1 XP to 10.2 XM`. This issue didn't occur on 10.1.XP. But in 10.2 XM,  When accessing or editing an item using the `experience editor` we are receiving a `403 "Access Denied"` message. The permissions for the profile haven't changed, the user is set up as an Admin. Did anyone face this issue before?

[image]

Comment: Try going to the path in the snapshot for Content Editor.aspx and check its Security settings. Check if IISUser and your machine user has read/write access to this file. If not, that can be the causing it. Ideally, it is preferred that IISUser and your machine user shall have full permissions on your Sitecore application's root folder.

Answer (score 1):

That error looks more like a file-based one, rather than a Sitecore permissions issue.

Please can you try ensuring the app pool that is running the Sitecore instance has access to that file?

To do this go to the root of the application and ensure the user:

iis apppool\yoursitecoreapp.com

Has read/write permission to all files and folders.